# Bootstrap Classes not working in jquery

Tags: jquery

Why Bootstrap classes are not working in jquery ? I am including all scripts correctly !

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign').click( function() {

   alert('Hi');




    })




});
```

Comment: Missing `.` with `glyphicon-exclamation-sign`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign` are 2 class names, it should be :

```
$('.glyphicon.glyphicon-exclamation-sign').click(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write something like this..

```
    $(document).ready( function() {
    $('.glyphicon, .glyphicon-exclamation-sign').click( function() {

   alert('Hi');
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.glyphicon-exclamation-sign').click( function() {
       alert('Hi');
    });
});
```

```css
span i{
 margin-top:50px;
 margin-left:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Click On Icon

<span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></i></span>
```